# More than 1000 CPU solo mining = bitcoin?

Tags: cgminer, mining-profitability, solo-mining, cpu-mining

If I have 1000 (or more) machines with CPU (and no GPU) solo mining (12 hours/day), will it be profitable?

Forget about the costs of electricity, etc...

I want to know if doing more than 1000 machines solo mining (CPU) will win any bitcoin?

Comment: Seems like you are a botnet operator...

Comment: actualy i´m thinking about the possibility. If it is profitable or not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If those are reasonably decent CPUs, they could be able to mine up to 20 Mhash/s each. Together, that's 20 Ghash/s, or the same as a small ASIC, and using massively more electricity.

As of december 2013, with the difficulty at 707408283, this means that you'd have approximately a 0.85% chance per month to win a block (worth 25 BTC).

Comment: nice! Tks! tell me... out of the possibility to win a block,  just the act of "mining" win some bitcoin?

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking now.

Comment: Oh, if you don't solo-mine, and join a pool, you will earn approximately the same on average (0.85% * 25 BTC = 0.21 BTC per month).